# Docker swarm UCP issues : no route host randomly between containers

Tags: docker, uucp

We are using `docker swarm UCP (Mirantis)` as an orchestrator for our containers, we have 10 nodes `(Redhat 8)` on our cluster to server more than `+130 docker service` (`+700 container`), we have also a huge number of bridge networks to limit access between containers for security raisons, sometimes randomly container can't communicate with each others due to `No route to Host` error, sometimes we restart the client and the server container to resolve this issue but it's not the case for all times, we switched LB mode From `VIP` to `DNSRR` but we still have the same issues sometimes, sometimes when we ping to a docker service we got a wrong IP adresse, did you ever have this issues and how to debug to resolve it.